# Hide/Remove video button from App Bar using CameraCaptureTask

Tags: windows-phone-8, appbar, cameracapturetask

Is there any way to hide or remove the video button from the App Bar on a WP8 application using CameraCaptureTask? Our app only includes taking pictures, no videos. That's why we think it would be better remove the video button if it isn't really a choice. CameraCaptureTask (native task) keeps the video button disabled but visible, instead hide it...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in short, no, there is no way to modify a native task in that manner.

That said, there is a way around this, be it a little more laborous.

You're going to need to create your own camera capture page.

Here is the official MSDN Documentation and code on how to accomplish this. 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359/sourcecode?fileId=62725&pathId=1134966225

If it were me I would make a control that pops open when you need it that does the MSDN example.

Good luck to you and welcome to Windows Phone dev. If you want faster answers hit me up on the tweeter. @Anth0nyRussell

Comment: Thank you Anthony. We already "suspected" it was not possible. But our app doesn't need a custom camera control. We think the video button isn't a compelling reason to create our own camera capture page. But thanks for all.